# Java Timer Memory Leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm experiencing what I think is a memory leak, but I can't really explain it.

I have a Class, in which can start a task.

```
public class TestSingleton {

   void start(){
      var task = new ScheduledTask();
      task.run();
   }

   static void setNextRequest(Date date){
      var task = new ScheduledTask();
      if(date != null){
         var timer = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(task, date);
      }else{
         task.run();
      }

   }


}
```

```
public class ScheduledTSLUpdate extends TimerTask {

   @Override
   public void run(){
      String request = "http://localhost:2374";

      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();

      HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
             .GET()
             .uri(URI.create(request))
             .headers(
                  "Authorization",
                  "Bearer " + Configuration.config.getProperty("JWTTOKEN"))
             .build();
      HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(httpRequest,   HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());

      ResponseEntity responseEntity = new Gson().fromJson(response, ResponseEntity.class);


      TestClass.setNextRequest(responseEntity.date);
   }

}
```

Apparently, when I call start(), I get a memory leak, and eventually an OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space. In theory, the Timer and ScheduledTask Objects should be garbage collected after execution(?).

Please help me, I'm really at a loss here.

**Edit:**

Screenshot showing the Exception (I used GSON for deserialization)

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and a full stack trace. Yours doesn't match the code you posted.

Comment: From your stack trace, your `setNextRequest` is calling `run`, but that's not shown in your sample here. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, well...do you see the recursion now?

Comment: Yep :)  I was too focused on the timer issue that I completely ignored that obvious mistake. Thanks a lot, kind stranger

Answer (score -1):

Each time you run the task, it spawns a new task recursively, so obviously it will not stop until you run out of memory.

If you want to repeat a task, see [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

Comment: Okay thanks, my problem is though, that I can't run the task at a fixed rate, since the outcome of the task determines when the next one is going to run.

Comment: hmm, ok, needs more thought. But you need to remove the recursion anyway.

Comment: `schedule` will run the task in the future and the `Timer` will forget about it. With this model, there should only ever be one task scheduled or running. Why do you think that will OOM?